# PowToon alternative

Tags: gratis, presentation

For work we have to make a presentation and would love to use something like  [PowToon](https://www.powtoon.com/).

I made a presentation using the free program but the premade figures and a few other things now have watermarks and the only way to get rid of them is to buy the Pro version.  I don't want to have to pay for this as it's a one-time presentation and there's no way to get reimbursed.

Are there any other programs like this that are free?

Comment: http://alternativeto.net/software/powtoon/?license=free

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of alternatives, but, as the commentators above have quite correctly noted, it depends on the "specs" of your presentation.

When I needed to make a user story video, I used [Animaker](https://www.animaker.com) and I thought that they were quite good. I thought the characters were appealing, and the video-making platform was quite easy to use as well. Although it is a subscription-based platform for making animated videos, they have a free tier with a few characters. You can make videos of up to 2 mins and export them in SD quality on a free tier.

Alternatively, if you know what you want to make and how to make it, [GoAnimate](https://goanimate.com) has 14 days free trial. If you manage to make all you want in 14 days, you can probably have your video. But I personally have not tried it and cannot advise you on how easy/intuitive it is to use and how appealing the characters/scenes are.